# AccessControlException user=root,access=WRITE... when using Kafka Connect HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-kafka, connector, confluent-platform

I'm using Confluent's distribution of Hadoop and trying to funnel messages from Kafka (on a different machine) to HDFS. The 'owner' on the HDFS side is 'hadoop'.

The error is common enough, and I've tried setting HADOOP_USER_NAME=hadoop but I still get the same error referencing 'root' as the user.  kafka-connect-hdfs has additional auth parameters, but they appear to all be for Kerberos, which is not engaged here.

> Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException):
>   Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/topics":hadoop:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x

Answer (score 0):

Just realized there wasn't a user named "hadoop" on the client, that seemed to do the trick.